# File empty on all asset uploads

Tags: assets, error-message, php

I've already adjusted the php.ini with max values for timeout and file size. This is really perplexing me. I'm on Dreamhost VPS. I've triple checked all file permissions. I consistently get this error: "Upload failed for brooklyn_bridge.jpg. The error message was: “Error uploading the file: Uploaded file was empty" no matter what I try.

Here was a recent error after turning devmode on:

```
$_FILES=array (
  'assets-upload' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'brooklyn_bridge.jpg',
    'type' => '',
    'tmp_name' => '',
    'error' => 6,
    'size' => 0,
  ),
)

$_COOKIE=array (
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389acusername' => 'fef6a177a0a30714376a5da4ec0d0f325256546as:60:"19b3e1b40c907258470bb0eada9aea0a67c491cdczo2OiJqb3NodWEiOw==";',
  'CraftSessionId' => 'XgGRKqGqqi1,Yosu0A37i0',
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac' => 'dfb0e07d4a3e09dd9d62a5b04372e50bb9480660s:396:"315becd5240726fc3c5e92aca8e9c9b29fc61fdfYTo2OntpOjA7czo2OiJqb3NodWEiO2k6MTtzOjMyOiJIelM3UzhNWER0ODNlbEdmRUlTUXhORnFXOVFrRVUzbiI7aToyO3M6MzY6IjM4MmM2YzllLTY3NjItNGNiMy1iNjkzLTAxZjZmODQ2MTRmZiI7aTozO2k6MDtpOjQ7czoxMjE6Ik1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChNYWNpbnRvc2g7IEludGVsIE1hYyBPUyBYIDEwXzExXzUpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS81MC4wLjI2NjEuMTAyIFNhZmFyaS81MzcuMzYiO2k6NTthOjA6e319";',
)

$_SESSION=array (
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac__id' => '1',
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac__name' => 'joshua',
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac__states' => 
  array (
  ),
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac__timeout' => 1465416905,
  'b8d03c16c0ad94ea360e045e078389ac__auth_access' => 
  array (
    0 => 'uploadToAssetSource:36',
  ),
  'assetsSourcesBeingIndexed' => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
  ),
  'assetsMissingFolders' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Comment: Here was a recent error after turning devmode on:

Comment: What's the devMode error?

Comment: @JoshuaTuscan, you have us in suspense. Did you ever work this out? And did you try a handful of different file types to confirm the same thing happens across the board?

Comment: It was an issue with the /tmp folder filling up. Have to regularly make sure it's emptied.

Comment: Weird. Would you mind posting that as an answer and accepting it, @JoshuaTuscan? It's good for posterity and scoring yourself a few more points. :)

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the /tmp folder filling up. Have to regularly make sure it's emptied. If the /tmp folder has proper permissions this should happen automatically.